# What is a better wording for "agreed proposal"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-request

When I write emails discussing about sending follow up (e.g. meeting notes, invoices, etc) about proposal that both party (my party and other party/client) have both agreed upon, I usually write like this:

> Based on the agreed proposal, we want to send you...

But each time I can't help but feel that "agreed proposal" feels a little bit off. If it's me, I want to rewrite it as "Based on the proposal that we mutually agreed, ..." but it feels like a mouthful.

Is there a concise and better way to rephrase that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it sounds perfectly fine. I can only suggest you use synonyms of "proposal" e.g.

> Based on the agreed **outline**/**plan**, we want to send you ...

Comment: Oh okay, that definitely sounds way better. I don't know that outline and plan be used in place of proposal. Thanks!